# ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.5 port 22: Connection refused but everything works fine

Tags: 20.04, ssh

I am trying to SSH into my Ubuntu server but I can't connect.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and OpenSSH-server and ssh is installed.

I also set a key with ssh-keygen

Comment: Did you create a key on your server by running `ssh-keygen`?

Comment: Did you create a RSA key?

Comment: Yes I did create a key